# not sure if my test passed capybara rspec devise sign in page factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

This is my sign_in spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'user can sign in' do 
  before(:each) do 
    @user = Factory(:user) 
    visit ('/users/sign_in') do 
      #login_as(@user, :scope => :user)
      fill_in('Email', :with => @user.email)
      fill_in('Password', :with => @user.password)
      click_button('Sign in')
    end 
    expect(page).to have_content 'Signed in successfully'
  end
end
```

I am using factory girl to make a test user data.

Here is my factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do 
    email 'yourself@example.com'
    password 'gibberishdotcom'
    password_confirmation 'gibberishdotcom'
  end 
end
```

I am using database cleaner to clean out the test environment.

Here is my spec_helper,

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
#require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'database_cleaner'


include Warden::Test::Helpers 
Warden.test_mode!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  #use database cleaner instead
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do 
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end 

  config.before :each do  
    DatabaseCleaner.start 
  end 

  config.after :each do 
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end 
end
```

I am trying to test my devise sign in page.

I am using rails 4 and here are my gems

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.1' #bdd testing framework
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.3.0' #acceptance test framework
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.42.0' #browser automation
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0" #make sample data for tests
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.3.0' #clean out test db environment
end
```

when I do rake -t I am getting this my server log

```
Judys-MacBook-Air:berklee-admissions-portal judyngai$ rake -t
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke spec:prepare (first_time)
** Execute spec:prepare
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute spec
/Users/judyngai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby -I/Users/judyngai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@berkeleycollegeofmusic/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib:/Users/judyngai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@berkeleycollegeofmusic/gems/rspec-support-3.0.0/lib -S /Users/judyngai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@berkeleycollegeofmusic/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/exe/rspec ./spec/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller_spec.rb ./spec/features/home_spec.rb ./spec/features/registrations_spec.rb ./spec/features/sign_in_spec.rb
No examples found.


Finished in 0.15487 seconds (files took 2.41 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /Users/judyngai/Desktop/berkeleycollegeofmusic/berklee-admissions-portal/coverage. 118 / 158 LOC (74.68%) covered.
** Execute default
```

my sign_in_spec.rb is in spec/features

It is loading it, but it's not seeing it.  This is my first time using factory girl. Am I mocking incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In feature specs, you typically write scenarios for your assertions. You probably want to model your feature specs more like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'user signs in' do
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  scenario 'with valid credentials' do
    visit('/users/sign_in')
    fill_in('Email', :with => user.email)
    fill_in('Password', :with => user.password)
    click_button('Sign in')
    expect(page).to have_content 'Signed in successfully'
  end

  scenario 'with invalid password' do
    visit('/users/sign_in')
    fill_in('Email', :with => user.email)
    fill_in('Password', :with => 'bananas')
    click_button('Sign in')
    expect(page).to have_content 'Email or password are invalid'
  end
end
```

You'll see that your assertions typically follow the pattern `expect(page).to` or `expect(page).to_not`.

Examples:

```
expect(page).to have_content user.email
expect(page).to have_css('.post', count: 1)
```

Comment: what does `let(:user) { Factory(:user) }` return user in? I am getting email undefined for @user because @user is now undefined.

Comment: I am getting `undefined method Factory for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserCanSignIn:0x00000104cadca8>`

Comment: Another edit to illustrate testing multiple scenarios. Also changed `let!` statement to use `FactoryGirl.create`.

Comment: One last edit to change the scenarios to use `expect(page)`. Sorry, I didn't realize that newer versions of RSpec/Capybara preferred that syntax. Just learned that yesterday on a new project.